# Reserved word in XML parsing?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have the following:

```
<?php

#Load in File
$xmlUrl ="http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/mlb/news";
$ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);

# -> Setup XML
$newsStory = $ConvertToXml->channel;

# -----> Load News Stories
for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){

    // Source of Article Info-->
    $SrcTitle=$newsStory[$i]->title;
    $SrcLink=$newsStory[$i]->link;

    // Actual News Article Info -->
    $title=$newsStory[$i]->item->title;
    $desc=$newsStory[$i]->item->description;


    echo '<hr>';
    echo '<strong>'.'Title:'.$title.'</strong>'.'(via: <a href=\''.$SrcLink.'\'>'.$SrcTitle.'</a>'.'<br />';
    //echo 'Link:'.$link.'<br />';
    echo 'Description'.$desc.'<br>';
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

It outputs just 1 result when it should output about 10 results...

This line: `$SrcLink=$newsStory[$i]->link;` the "link" word appears to possibly be a 'reserved' word here since its purple on my editor as shown in the image below:

[image: img]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not reserved, your editor just thinks you're invoking [`link()`](http://php.net/link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your IDE is highlighting that purple, but here is the problem:

```
$newsStory = $ConvertToXml->channel;
```

needs to be changed to:

```
$newsStory = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
```

Each entry in the RSS feed is in an <item> tag so you need to be looping over those for the actual feed entries.

Comment: Great help! Appreciate it Drew!

Comment: You're welcome.  Meant to add it earlier but, the `channel` data is feed specific information.  So the `title` and `link` you were printing were the feed title and feed URL.  Beyond that, each `item` is an entry in the feed.  That's why you were seeing 1 thing get printed out before.

Answer (score 0):

Colour-coding often suffers from this problem. Since the word is being used as a property name (as shown by the `->`), it can be literally anything - there are no reserved words in this case.

I would suggest `var_dump(count($newsStory))` so you can see exactly how many elements there are to loop through. If it's `1`, then you probably have an issue with your `$newsStory` variable - you can `var_dump` that too.